# Azure B2C and Login Hint

Tags: azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-ad-b2c

I'm working with Azure Mobile Apps to host my site.  I'm using B2C to control authentication.

If I make the following call to login (in this case from a browser):

```
https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad
```

Then I get my company branding login settings just fine.  Images, etc. are great.

But I want to fill in the username for convenience.

So if I make this call to login (same client):

```
https://mydomain.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad?login_hint=myemail@gmail.com
```

Then the login name (login_hint) value shows up in the username field just great, but all my company branding is lost.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?  I tried `domain_hint` just flailing about and it didn't work, either.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This same thing happens in a webview in a native Xamarin client, as I would have expected.  I was just confirming it.

Comment: What policy are you using? Sign in? The unified signup/signin?

Comment: Also, when you say company branding, do you mean this:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-reference-ui-customization

Comment: Saca - using Sign in policy, not unified. Also, company branding which you can find under "users and groups" in the portal.  Not page UI  customization.

Comment: Page UI customization works great for login_hint, but not for forcePasswordResetNextLogin.  Page UI Customization fails for that.

Answer (score 4):

This is by design.

If the login hint was not a gmail account or another account that doesn't match your tenant domain, then you wouldn't lose it.  If you give a login hint for your user in your tenant, then you will have your company branding.

Comment: Hmm.  That might make more sense to me if this was pure AD.  I've set my local accounts to `email` so that any email can be used to login.  Since my request is bouncing through my Azure Mobile App Easy Auth site and then on to B2C, shouldn't my domain already be passed along?  Otherwise, how would it know that I was using myemail@gmail.com for MY tenant and not another one?